# Error accessing remote server but not locally

Tags: delphi, winapi

I am coding with BDS 2006 Win32 on a Windows 10 Home Premium OS and Dell Inspiron N7110 laptop.

I have created a simple client-server program using `TSocketConnection` on the client side.  It runs fine locally.  The server-side form pops up when connected by the client.  I see my client dataset data on the client fine, too.

PROBLEM: When the client app attempts to access the app server on a PC in my office, the remote server form still pops up on this other PC (indicating that a connection was made), however, when the client app attempts to open the client dataset, it receives an "error loading Midas.dll" message.  This happens in design mode or run time when addressing the remote PC.

FYI: (still connecting to the remote PC) with the `TSocketConnection.Host` set to `"IPMServer.ddns.net"`, the client `TSocketConnection` finds and properly resolves the `ServerName` and `ServerGUID` in design mode and the client dataset "sees" the RDM table's data source provider.  However, the client dataset receives the Midas error when I attempt to set the client dataset `Active` property to True.

FYI 2:  TO ENSURE THAT MY CLIENT APP FINDS THE REMOTE SERVER ON MY LAN... I am using a URL redirection service to my DDNS URL.  My router supports NAT loopback.  I have the PC remote server IP address reserved on my LAN. My LAN forwards all `TSocketConnection.Port` calls to the app server.  The remote PC Windows Firewall allows the remote server to send to the client.  Again, I see the remote server form pop up on the remote PC box.

More FYI's:  About eight years ago, I successfully created a `TWebConnection` client-server system using the same approach and tools.  The OS's were most likely XP boxes.  It ran fine.

I also have recently created a client-server system using just XE2 and Indy components using the same hardware and URL redirection strategy that I am using for the `TSocketConnection` app.  This "just Delphi and Indy" works fine.  I have created two versions of this "just Delphi and Indy" approach.  One with client datasets on the client side and one using Component Ace's Absolute database on the client side.  The remote server uses ADO and Firebird in all described systems.  Both of these work great with no Datasnap at all! (but a couple thousand lines of code not needed by Datasnap).

RECAP:  My `TSocketConnect` client-server system works fine locally.  When I try to draw data from the same application server on a PC on my LAN, the remote server connects but the client receives the "error loading Midas.dll" message.

!!!  Just remembered...Whether I compile the client with or without the MidasLib in the `uses` clause, my client EXE is the same size.  I don't understand how this is related to my problem.

Comment: So, does this "error loading Midas.dll" originate on the remote server?  Does the server app use Midas.Dll? If so, is Midas.Dll correctly registered on the remore server (do you know how to check)? Have you tried remote-debugging the server app on the remote server from BDS2006 on your laptop? There is is lot of info like this missing from your q.

Comment: I understand how overwhelming my pleas might have sounded. Obviously, I am drowning and lost, or I wouldn't have come here.My understanding is that the application server and its remote data module do not require or use midas.dll.

Comment: more... Ok, my client app includes MidasLib in the main form's USES statement. I started a new project.  This client app correctly accepts the MidesLib in USES.  and..and this is embarrassing...None of the previous problems I describe occur if I make my DEV laptop the server, instead of the PC box.  I have two other laptops (XP and Win7) and both correctly connect and display data with the client dataset when the remote application server is on my DEV laptop. I've wasted WAY too much of our time.  If I discover what was wrong. I'll share. Thanks for your reply.